# Is ColdFusion compiled?

Tags: html, coldfusion

I have a client wanting a 3rd party, lead gen popup script installed in a few of her sites. One of which is built in ColdFusion, which I've never even looked at before. I'm wondering is dropping the code into a .cfm file as easy as dropping it into a PHP file? Can I just open the right file in a text editor, drop the code in and all is ok? Or do I need to use adobe product and recompile or anything like that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is just that easy, but in the same way that you have to have PHP running on the server in order for the .php file to be processed, you need ColdFusion running on the server in order for the .cfm file to be processed.

You don't compile the .cfm file yourself.  You just save time.cfm as:

`<cfoutput>#now()#</cfoutput>`

... upload it to the server, and open http://domain/time.cfm

If you change it to be prettier (in any text editor or IDE):

`<cfoutput>#dateFormat( now(), 'mm/dd/yyyy' )#</cfoutput>`

...save the file, upload it, and refresh the page in the browser.  *You* don't have to manually compile or recompile anything.

Comment: cool thanks, just didn't want to comit to a simple task then find myself needing a day to work out basics of cfm :)

Comment: No problem.  There's a lot of good CF people on SO.  Feel free to ask questions as they arise.

Comment: ColdFusion compiles the code you dropped into the .CFM or .CFC files into Java Bytecode. This makes all subsequent hits to that page very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is compiled.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=deploying_1.html

Comment: Just to clarify, it's compiled at run time on the server.  What the OP was asking was whether or not _he_ would have to compile his changes manually prior to uploading (he does not).

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood that OP already had a server with cf running.

Answer (score 0):

Remember if you have template caching on you may need to turn that off then back on after making code changes.  Same as preserve the .class files

In the CFamin they look like this:

Trusted cache 
When checked, any requested files found to currently reside in the template cache will not be inspected for potential updates. For sites where templates are not updated during the life of the server, this minimizes file system overhead. This setting does not require restarting the server.

Save class files 
When you select this option, the class files generated by ColdFusion are saved to disk for reuse after the server restarts. Adobe recommends this for production systems. During development, Adobe recommends that you do not select this option.